# is theres a way to filter data from one sheet to another within the same worksheet on google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-forms

i linked a google form with a google sheets and have the responses all together on there. my question is if there's a way to create separate sheets in the same document that only shows even rows and another one that only show odd rows. so far i color-coded them (so even=green and odd=yellow). i want to separate onto individual sheets since one group will focus on the form's responses that are on odd rows in the sheet and then another group for the evens

if this doesn't make sense, i can try explaining it again. thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can build two different formulas that fetch the corresponding rows in each Sheet:

Having this table:

[image]

You can build two other sheets having this formulas:

```
// FOR EVEN

=ARRAYFORMULA(SORT(IF(NOT(ISODD(ROW(ANSWERS!A1:C9))), ANSWERS!A1:C9, ""), 1, FALSE))

// AND FOR ODD

=ARRAYFORMULA(SORT(IF(ISODD(ROW(ANSWERS!A1:C9)), ANSWERS!A1:C9, ""), 1, FALSE))
```

The `SORT` function is used so it will stack your answer leaving the blanks at the end.

### Sample Output:

Odd:[image]

Even:[image]